# PHP doesn't properly receive a $_POST variable using fetch

Tags: javascript, php, post, react-native, fetch

Using React-Native and fetch(), I want to create a new database entry using a PHP script. The PHP script itself is working, tested it successfully with an html page.
But I can't get my Javascript fetch() version working yet.

```
// App.js    

    const dbData = new FormData();
    dbData.append(
      'fileName', 'fileNameTest',
    );

    fetch('http://myurl.com/createDatabaseEntry.php', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
      method: 'POST',
      body: dbData,
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log('Database response: ', res);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('DB error: ', error);
    });
```

BTW: Network status in the logs is always 200.

The PHP side:

```
// createDatabaseEntry.php

$fileName = $_POST['fileName'];
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'login', 'password', 
'myDatabase');
$sql = "INSERT INTO files (fileName) VALUES ('$fileName')";
```

It's probably about passing the variables with fetch or the dbData.append()?

Comment: Check the Network tab to see what request parameters are being sent.

Comment: You don't need the `headers:` option, it will send that header by default when you use `FormData`.

Comment: Where do you `echo` a response from `php`?

Comment: Thank you guys. It was indeed about the parameters. I'll cut the headers: option out then, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two issues at code

1. No response is `echo`ed from `php`
2. You only log `Response` object, where you would probably expect to use `Response.json()`, `Response.text()`, `Response.arrayBuffer()` or `Response.blob()` to read response from `php` as `JSON`, plain text, an `ArrayBuffer` or a `Blob`

---

```
fetch('http://myurl.com/createDatabaseEntry.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: dbData,
})
.then(res => res.text()).then(text => console.log(text))
.catch(error => console.error('DB error: ', error));
```

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering why my console didn' output an actual error, even if I did log it. With that i could find out, that my DB needed an integer value, and I passed a string.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you connected to the database but did not execute INSERT statement.
Please do not forget 
1) arguments escaping
2) error processing

```
$filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $fileName);
$sql = "INSERT INTO files (fileName) VALUES ('$filename')";
if (true === mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    echo 'Insert done';
} else {
    echo 'Error: ' . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Comment: He said it works when he tests it with an HTML form. He probably just left that out of the question.